# How to search array of dates to determine if one or more fit within a defined range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, date

The problem I'm trying to solve is to determine if a user has created a "tip" last month. This check will be done after the user creates a new tip.

I have an array of strings of past tip dates for the user called "tip_dates". My current solution using rails steps through each value in that array, converts it to a date, and checks to see if it is within the month.

Is this the most efficient solution? I'm concerned that as the date array gets larger this check may take a lot of time.

```
def tip_last_month
    start_date = Date.today.beginning_of_month - 1.month
    end_date = start_date.end_of_month
    for tip_date in self.tip_dates do
        if tip_date.to_date.between?(start_date, end_date)
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby people dont really use `for` and explicit `return`-s at the end of the functions. The value of the last expression will get returned by default.

What i do here is that i create an array by mapping the string to date objects and then passing them to an `any?` block which will return true for the first match or return false if there is none.

```
def tip_last_month
  start_date = Date.today.beginning_of_month - 1.month
  end_date = start_date.end_of_month

  tip_dates.map(&:to_date).any? do |date|
    date.between?(start_date, end_date)
  end
end
```

It is true that as the array gets larger, this function will slow down. You should consider storing the tips in the database in a separate table, by having one record for each tip and query them by date. It will be much faster that way.

You can read more about associations here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thank you! What is "large" in your experience for this array in this situation? Basically, at what point would you prioritize fixing this performance issue?

Comment: If the application's main domain is around tips or I expect that users will add tips regularly over time (so the number of tips per user will grow over thusands). Basically i would go with a separate table any time except if the app is so simple that is doesnt worth the time to setup a separate table. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and thoughtful answers! Based on your answer I think I'm okay in the immediate.

Comment: What you have to consider is that by storing the tips this way, you'll parse and traverse the array every time a request comes in. If you put the tips in a separate table you'll got much higher performance by default and rails will also cache the SQL request for you, so the upcoming requests wont even use the db, they will get served from memory